# Can I think of the onStop hook of iron-router as similar to the template.templateName.destroyed callback

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have an idea about being able to consolidate several of my templates by taking advantage of the iron-router hooks. I just became aware of the onStop and it seems that it may handle things that I currently handle in my template.destroyed callback.

I do very little in my template.destroyed callbacks for the templates that I want to consolidate and they each are paired up with separate routes. If I can do this, I can keep the individual routes, use the onStop hook, and make use of a single template for the separate routes. I hope that makes sense.

I'll give it a try, but wanted to get thoughts from others if this is a proper way to reason about this.

Comment: I have the same question too